# Bounced ray angle of normal direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, optics, vectors, reflection

### **TL;DR whats the position of C.**

I'm currently programming something and for some reason I having problem figuring this one out, imagine having a ray / or ball bouncing (without mass or gravity etc) and I want to know the position (C) of where it will end up when it collide with somthing that are at an angle.

$$A_x=-24$$

$$A_y= 40$$

$$B_x = -105$$

$$B_y = 25$$

Bnormal_direction_x = 0.22925

Bnormal_direction_y = 0.973367

$$C_x = ?$$

$$C_y = ?$$

**PS:**If I need add some more info let me know.

Thanks in advance.

[image: bounce ray[1]]

### **EDIT**

> This question is put on hold as off-topic, Homework-like questions

**....great**

I understand the confusion, just because I created an example and wrote it as simplified as possible so anyone could hopefully understand what I was trying to do, confused you mods to believing it to be an homework type of question, actually what this is for and I'm working on is really really really far from any type of homework or exercise stuff.

**P.S**: the reason I even asked this question to begin with were because nothing worked that I tried, now I have figured out the issue (why nothing I tried worked), it were because the software I was writting in its coordinates system is XZY insted of XYZ and that really messed up my calcs.

"Me getting bothered by the mods as usuall on these sites..."

**Here is how i solved it**. (*to bad I can't anwser my own question in the correct way becuase its put on hold)*

**Math:**
[image]

**Code/Math as text:**

```
---Point3 values for 3D for 2D use point2 values [x,y] or point3 but set z to 0 like i do in this example

A_pos = [50, 100, 0]; --shot from point XYZ
B_pos = [0, 0, 0]; -- collison point XYZ
D_pos = [-200, 0, 0]; -- XYZ
E_pos = [200, 0, 0]; -- XYZ 


AB_vector = (B_pos - A_pos); -- = [-50,-100,0]

ED_vector = (D_pos - E_pos); -- = [-400,0,0]

ED_magnitude = sqrt(((E_pos.x - D_pos.x)*(E_pos.x - D_pos.x)) + ((E_pos.y - D_pos.y)*(E_pos.y - D_pos.y)) + ((E_pos.z - D_pos.z)*(E_pos.z - D_pos.z))); -- Distance between D and E point  (400)

ED_vector_normalized = (ED_vector / ED_magnitude); -- [-1,0,0]

ED_normal = [ED_vector_normalized.z , ED_vector_normalized.y , ED_vector_normalized.x*-1]; -- ZY-X insted of XYZ , to rotated ED_vector_normalized  90deg, 
--you can change to diffrent XYZ, ZXY,ZY-X etc etc combos to get diffrent type of mirroring depending on what cordenate system you using.

ABED_dot_product = ((AB_vector.x*ED_normal.x) + (AB_vector.y*ED_normal.y)  + (AB_vector.z*ED_normal.z)); -- Dot product = (AB_vector dot ED_normal) 

C_pos = (AB_vector - (2*(ABED_dot_product)*ED_normal)) --- position of C (after the bounce)
```

**Code/Math as img (easier to read):**
[image]
[image]

### **And tested with some diffrent angles:**

[image]

Comment: To keep it simple, you should also specify that friction is zero between the ball and ramp.  With friction, there will be a tangential force that will cause ball rotation and the bounce angle will be different.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using just geometric arguments.  If there are no other effects (gravity, etc.), then the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence on the plane.  So you are just left to calculate this angle and project it opposite of $\vec{N}$ to find $\vec{C}$.  To find the angle, take the dot product of the normal vector $\vec{N}$ and the vector pointing from the plane to the ball $\vec{R} = \vec{A}-\vec{B}$.  You end up with

$$\vec{N}\cdot\vec{R} = \left|\vec{N}\right|\left|\vec{R}\right|\cos(\theta) = N_xR_x+N_yR_y$$

So,

$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\vec{N}\cdot\vec{R}}{|\vec{N}||\vec{R}|}\right)$$

Knowing this angle, you can now rotate the vector $\vec{N}$ about the $z$-axis (keeping the vector in the $x$-$y$ plane) to find the vector components of $\vec{C}$ as:

$$C_x = \cos(\theta)N_x-\sin(\theta)N_y$$
$$C_y = \sin(\theta)N_x+\cos(\theta)N_y$$

Now, this is just a vector that points in the direction of $\vec{C}$.  The magnitude of $\vec{C}$ will depend on the time of the observation and the initial speed of the object, etc.